# Sorting list per digits in string

Tags: python, string, dictionary, digits, sorting

I have a `dict`, like so:

```
IdSet = {
    u'abcd_def_99': [u'Scenario: forth Scenario'],
    u'abcd_def_10': [u'Scenario: eleventh Scenario'],
    u'abcd_def_100': [u'Scenario: second Scenario'],
    u'abcd_def_101': [u'Scenario: ninth Scenario'],
    u'abcd_def_46': [u'Scenario: tenth Scenario', u'Scenario: third Scenario', u'Scenario: fifth Scenario'],
}
```

I'd like to reassemble the list in ascending order by the number (digits) only (but still keeping the entire `referenceId`, and the value):

```
10
46
99
100
101
```

The problem is, `sorted(IdSet)` doesn't assemble in the order I'd like, however like so:

```
10
100
101
46
99
```

The sorted method is not working the way I want it to, so my code must be wrong somewhere. I did think about filtering out for the digits, then sorting, like so:

```
    for i, item in enumerate(IdSet.items()):
            item_holder = item[0]
            m = re.search(r'\d+$', item_holder).group()
```

Basically what I'd like to write is:

```
for key in dict:
    convert string to its numerical value
    then sort key in ascending order, keeping the values
```

Would anyone have any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that applying `sorted` to a `dict` will yield a `list`. For obtaining a sorted `dict` you have to turn to [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

It really depends on the structur of your keys. If `abcd_def_` is constant you can use a `key` function for `sorted`.

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sorted):

> key specifies a function of one argument that is used to extract a
>   comparison key from each list element: key=str.lower. The default
>   value is None (compare the elements directly).

```
sorted(IdSet, key=lambda x:int(x[9:]))
```

If the last elements are guaranteed to be the digits:

```
sorted(IdSet, key=lambda x:int(x.split("_")[-1))
```

If the digit can be anywhere in the expression you will have to `re.search`.

```
sorted(IdSet, key=lambda x:int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group()))
```

**interpreter**

```
>>> IdSet = {u'abcd_def_99': [u'Scenario: forth Scenario'],
     u'abcd_def_10': [u'Scenario: eleventh Scenario'],
     u'abcd_def_100': [u'Scenario: second Scenario'],
     u'abcd_def_101': [u'Scenario: ninth Scenario'],
     u'abcd_def_46': [u'Scenario: tenth Scenario', u'Scenario: third Scenario', u'Scenario: fifth Scenario'],
     }

>>> print sorted(IdSet, key=lambda x:int(x[9:]))
```

**output**

```
[u'abcd_def_10', u'abcd_def_46', u'abcd_def_99', u'abcd_def_100', u'abcd_def_101']
```

**regex**

```
>>> IdSet = {u'abcd_def_99_foo': [u'Scenario: forth Scenario'],
     u'abcd_def_10_foo': [u'Scenario: eleventh Scenario'],
     }
>>> import re
>>> print sorted(IdSet, key=lambda x:int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group()))
```

**output regex**

```
[u'abcd_def_10_foo', u'abcd_def_99_foo']
```

Convert it into an `OrderedDict`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(sorted(IdSet, key=lambda x:int(re.search(r'\d+', x).group())))
```

Answer (score 1):

If your keys are consistent, try this:

```
sorted(IdSet.keys(), key=lambda x: int(x.split('_')[-1]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two specific issues out here

1. You need to understand that dictionary are not ordered. Even if you sort it, it would rearrange the elements on some intrinsic ordering. You should be better off using `OrderedDict`
2. When you are sorting the keys which is a string. Lexicographical ordering is different from numeric ordering. You should consider only the numeric part by modifying the key and stripping out everything, except the numeric portion by which you would want to order the dictionary key.

### Implementation

```
from collections import OrderedDict
OrderedDict(sorted(IdSet.items(), key = lambda e: int(e[0].split('_')[-1])))
```